# Understanding min_df and max_df in scikit CountVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I have five text files that I input to a CountVectorizer. When specifying `min_df` and `max_df` to the CountVectorizer instance what does the min/max document frequency exactly mean? Is it the frequency of a word in its particular text file or is it the frequency of the word in the entire overall corpus (five text files)?

What are the differences when `min_df` and `max_df` are provided as integers or as floats?

[The documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn-feature-extraction-text-countvectorizer) doesn't seem to provide a thorough explanation nor does it supply an example to demonstrate the use of these two parameters. Could someone provide an explanation or example demonstrating `min_df` and `max_df`?

Answer (score 352, accepted):

`max_df` is used for removing terms that appear **too frequently**, also known as "corpus-specific stop words". For example:

- `max_df = 0.50` means "ignore terms that appear in **more than 50% of the documents**".
- `max_df = 25` means "ignore terms that appear in **more than 25 documents**".

The default `max_df` is `1.0`, which means "ignore terms that appear in **more than 100% of the documents**". Thus, the default setting does not ignore any terms.

---

`min_df` is used for removing terms that appear **too infrequently**. For example:

- `min_df = 0.01` means "ignore terms that appear in **less than 1% of the documents**".
- `min_df = 5` means "ignore terms that appear in **less than 5 documents**".

The default `min_df` is `1`, which means "ignore terms that appear in **less than 1 document**". Thus, the default setting does not ignore any terms.

Comment: Wish this appeared in the official doc to avoid much unclarity and confusion.

Answer (score 17):

I would add this point also for understanding `min_df` and `max_df` in tf-idf better.

If you go with the default values, meaning considering all terms, you have generated definitely more tokens. So your clustering process (or any other thing you want to do with those terms later) will take a longer time.

BUT the quality of your clustering should NOT be reduced.

One might think that allowing all terms (e.g. too frequent terms or stop-words) to be present might lower the quality but in tf-idf it doesn't. Because tf-idf measurement instinctively will give a low score to those terms, effectively making them not influential (as they appear in many documents).

So to sum it up, pruning the terms via `min_df` and `max_df` is to improve the performance, not the quality of clusters (as an example).

And the crucial point is that if you set the `min` and `max` mistakenly, you would lose some important terms and thus lower the quality. So if you are unsure about the right threshold (it depends on your documents set), or if you are sure about your machine's processing capabilities, leave the `min`, `max` parameters unchanged.

Comment: Thank you - this is the same conclusion I have reached independently.

Answer (score 13):

As per the `CountVectorizer` documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).

When using a float in the range `[0.0, 1.0]` they refer to the **document** frequency. That is the percentage of documents that contain the term.

When using an int it refers to absolute number of documents that hold this term.

Consider the example where you have 5 text files (or documents). If you set `max_df = 0.6` then that would translate to `0.6*5=3` documents. If you set `max_df = 2` then that would simply translate to 2 documents.

The source code example below is copied from Github [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py) and shows how the `max_doc_count` is constructed from the `max_df`. The code for `min_df` is similar and can be found on the GH page.

```
max_doc_count = (max_df
                 if isinstance(max_df, numbers.Integral)
                 else max_df * n_doc)
```

The defaults for `min_df` and `max_df` are 1 and 1.0, respectively. This basically says *"If my term is found in only 1 document, then it's ignored. Similarly if it's found in all documents (100% or 1.0) then it's ignored."*

`max_df` and `min_df` are both used internally to calculate `max_doc_count` and `min_doc_count`, the maximum and minimum number of documents that a term must be found in. This is then passed to [`self._limit_features`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L665) as the keyword arguments `high` and `low` respectively, the docstring for `self._limit_features` is

```
"""Remove too rare or too common features.

Prune features that are non zero in more samples than high or less
documents than low, modifying the vocabulary, and restricting it to
at most the limit most frequent.

This does not prune samples with zero features.
"""
```

Comment: This is confusing. The documentation for `min_df` says 'ignore terms that have a document frequency **strictly lower** than the given threshold.' So frequency strictly lower than the default of 1 would mean to ignore terms that never appear (!) but keep terms that appear once.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck is correct. This answer misinterprets the precise meanings of `min_df` and `max_df`. I added an answer that explains exactly how these parameters are interpreted by CountVectorizer.

Comment: yeah, this is answer is somewhat wrong as @MonicaHeddneck and kevin pointed out, both for min_df and max_df

Answer (score 5):

The defaults for min_df and max_df are 1 and 1.0, respectively. These defaults really don't do anything at all.

That being said, I believe the currently accepted answer by @Ffisegydd answer isn't quite correct.

For example, run this using the defaults, to see that when `min_df=1` and `max_df=1.0`, then

1) all tokens that appear in at least one document are used  (e.g., all tokens!)

2) all tokens that appear in all documents are used (we'll test with one candidate: everywhere).

```
cv = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=1.0, lowercase=True) 
# here is just a simple list of 3 documents.
corpus = ['one two three everywhere', 'four five six everywhere', 'seven eight nine everywhere']
# below we call fit_transform on the corpus and get the feature names.
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus)
vocab = cv.get_feature_names()
print vocab
print X.toarray()
print cv.stop_words_
```

We get:

```
[u'eight', u'everywhere', u'five', u'four', u'nine', u'one', u'seven', u'six', u'three', u'two']
[[0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]]
set([])
```

All tokens are kept. There are no stopwords.

Further messing around with the arguments will clarify other configurations.

For fun and insight, I'd also recommend playing around with `stop_words = 'english'` and seeing that, peculiarly, all the words except 'seven' are removed! Including `everywhere'.

Answer (score 2):

The goal of `MIN_DF` is to ignore words that have very few occurrences to be considered meaningful. For example, in your text you may have names of people that may appear in only 1 or two documents. In some applications, this may qualify as noise and could be eliminated from further analysis. Similarly, you can ignore words that are too common with `MAX_DF`.

Instead of using a minimum/maximum term frequency (total occurrences of a word) to eliminate words, `MIN_DF` and `MAX_DF` look at how many documents contained a term, better known as document frequency. The threshold values can be an absolute value (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4) or a value representing proportion of documents (e.g. 0.25 meaning, ignore words that have appeared in 25% of the documents) .

See [some usage examples here](https://kavita-ganesan.com/how-to-use-countvectorizer/#CountVectorizer-and-Stop-Words).

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the documentation for sklearn CountVectorizer.This is how I think about it.

Common words have higher frequency values, while rare words have lower frequency values. The frequency values range between `0 - 1` as fractions.

`max_df` is the upper ceiling value of the frequency values, while `min_df` is just the lower cutoff value of the frequency values.

If we want to remove more common words, we set `max_df` to a lower ceiling value between 0 and 1. If we want to remove more rare words, we set `min_df` to a higher cutoff value between 0 and 1. We keep everything between `max_df` and `min_df`.

Let me know, not sure if this makes sense.