# What is minDF parameter of CountVectorizer in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I read spark document, which said

> During the fitting process, `CountVectorizer` will select the top `vocabSize` words ordered by term frequency across the corpus. An optional parameter `minDF` also affects the fitting process by specifying the minimum number (or fraction if < 1.0) of documents a term must appear in to be included in the vocabulary.

Could anyone explain it to me more clearly?

Comment: I think this says it all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697766/understanding-min-df-and-max-df-in-scikit-countvectorizer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**minDF** is used for removing terms that appear too infrequently.

For example:
minDF = 0.01 means "ignore terms that appear in less than 1% of the documents".
minDF = 5 means "ignore terms that appear in less than 5 documents".

The default minDF is 1, which means "ignore terms that appear in less than 1 document". Thus, the default setting does not ignore any terms.

**vocabSize** is the maximum number of tokens you can have in your vocabulary. The default is 1 << 18. I.e., 2^18 or 262,144.

*minDF*: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/ml/feature.py#L430-L435
*vocabSize*: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/ml/feature.py#L444-L446