# Use at the same time min_df, max_df and max_features in Scikit TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I am trying to figure out wether I can use `min_df`, `max_df` and `max_features` at the same time as arguments of the TfidfVectorizer class from Scikit.Sklearn. I perfectly understand what each of them is for.

I have passed a data to TfidfVectorizer() fixing `min_df = 0.05` and `max_df = 0.95` that meaning that the terms appearing in less of 5% of my documents are ignored and the same with those appearing in more than 95% of my documents (as explained in 
[Understanding min_df and max_df in scikit CountVectorizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697766/understanding-min-df-and-max-df-in-scikit-countvectorizer)).

Like this, my data, after doing TF-IDF has 360 columns. However, this is way too much so I would like to set `max_features = 100`. However, when I print the shape of my new data after being transformed, I still get 360 columns, instead of 100 as I was supposed to get.

I also tried to fix just `max_features = 100` to check if without the other parameters it would return just the 100 columns but it didn't, it actually has 952 columns. I read the documentation and it is saying that this parameter is supposed to return the top max_features, however I can't observe that.

Does anyone have a clue of what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate this with `max_features=100, min_df=0.05, max_df= 0.95` and the result was `<11858x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'`, so it worked as intended. Check if you're fitting the data with the vectorizer you created with `max_features`.

If you could provide your code, it could be easier to identify the problem.